# AngularJS: ui-router href rewrite into ui-sref

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a CMS which forces URLs to pages to be of a certain pattern.  We need to conditionally rewrite these link's hrefs.

The CMS will print on the page something like:

```
<a href="/path/to/the/zoo/gorilla.html">Go</a>
```

Our router needs to actually point to

```
#/zoo/gorilla
```

If we had written this link ourselves, it would look like:

```
<a ui-sref="zoo('gorilla')>Go</a>
```

The problem is, we can't always guarantee that the /zoo/gorilla part means we're at zoo('gorilla').

The easiest way would be to parse the CMS url in to the router URL and just do something like:

```
link.attr("href", "#/zoo/gorilla");
```

I understand why that is typically against the very idea of ui-router, but I'm hoping to find a way to use it for this one strange case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would work, basically a directive to change which URL you are headed towards when you click it.

```
module.directive('newHref', ['$location',function($location) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', newHref);

        function newHref(event) {
            var hrefList = event.target.href.split("/");
            var parent = hrefList[hrefList.length-2];
            var child = hrefList[hrefList.length-1].split(".")[0];

            $location.path("/" + hrefList.slice(0, hrefList.length-2).join("/") + "/" + parent + "/" + child);
        }
    }
}]);
```

Use it like:

```
<a href="/path/to/the/zoo/gorilla.html" new-href>Go</a>
```

Comment: I tried this before asking.  Changing the href would point the URL to the proper hash, but the state does not recognize this change.

Comment: @oooyaya changed the code to allow the router to see the change

Comment: This is what I did.  The problem was actually something else - using ui-router named sub-views and having to target them in the views object.  That's why the view never changed - I wasn't telling it where to go.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like stepping into dangerous zone, but you can create "href" directive which will replace value of `href` attribute automatically. No extra attributes needed, but it may make your code a bit ambiguous...

```
module
  .directive('href', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var ngUrl; // convert CMS url to Angular URL somehow
        if(attrs.href === '/path/to/the/zoo/gorilla.html') {
            ngUrl = '#/zoo/gorilla';
        }

        element[0].href = ngUrl;
    };
});
```

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/erykpiast/zog1yaxy/)

Comment: We did something similar.  Maybe its a false symptom.  The href does get changed, and the URL changes to what we want when we click it, but the view does not change.  Is there some obvious thing that means?  It matches a route, and the partial loads, but it never displays.